# Change color of a Button when its Pressed

Tags: angular2-nativescript

how do I do it in nativescript? I tried

```
.myButton:highlighting{
  background-color:#00A3FF;
}
```

It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

in nativescript 3+ use `:pressed` or `:highlighted` pseudo selector in your css/scss.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, it to set the css in JS, i.e

```
<button class="myButton" (click)="clicked($event) [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': color }"></button>
```

and then in your component, you would set the default (unclicked value) and then toggle the value of click:

```
class myCmp implements OnInit {
    color: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.color = 'green'
    }

    clicked(e) {
        this.color = this.color === 'green' ? 'red' : 'green';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can have two buttons and be switching each other based on condition -

```
<Button row="1" col="0" *ngIf="isTapped" text="Enable" class="activateButton" (tap)="buttonTapped('activate')"></Button>
<Button row="1" col="0" *ngIf="isNotTapped" text="Disable" class="deactivateButton" (tap)="buttonTapped('deactivate')"></Button>
```

**CSS**

```
.activatePackage {
color:white;
background-color: #68CF17;
margin-top: 5px; 
margin-right: 0px; 
font-size: 12px;
border-radius: 20;
height: 40;
}

.deactivatePackage {
border-width:1px;
border-color: #ED2830;
color:#ED2830;
background-color: white;
margin-top: 5px; 
margin-right: 0px; 
font-size: 12px;
border-radius: 20;
height: 40; 
}
```

**TS**

```
buttonTapped(args){
if(args=='activate'){
this.isTapped = true;
this.isNotTapped  = false;
}
else if(args=='deactivate'){
this.isTapped = false;
this.isNotTapped  = true;
}
```